# Get Squard value of number using for loop in java

Tags: java

***strong text***I m new to coding.. I m try to get square value of number using java. please help me for solving problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public double square(double x) {
  return x*x;
}
```

or

```
Math.pow(x, 2);
```